# How to add user input to script functions and variables in Python and interface with a database?

Tags: python-3.x, database, user-input, pysimplegui

I'm very new to Python and I've run into a wall. This script will run if you add someone from your iMessage contacts into "FrstNm LstNm". However, I'd like the button name, the text of the message, the recipient, and possibly the function name to all be user input. I know I'd probably need another window for the actual input action. None of that makes me scratch my head as much as how I'd get all of that input to reflect a newly saved button to be saved in a database? I ultimately plan on users having the ability to add more buttons and essentially copying the process all over button for button. I'm completely stumped and don't know where to begin. What would that look like? Any tips or resources would greatly help and be appreciated.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import sys
import subprocess
from os import system, name
from playsound import playsound

msg1 = "On a Call"             # I'd like the message sent to be user input
people = "FrstNm LstNm"        # I'd like Nms to be user input
layout = [[sg.Button('ON CALL')]]  #I'd like the button name 'ON CALL' to be user input

sg.SetOptions(font='Any')  
sg.theme('LightBlue')
window = sg.Window('Text', auto_size_buttons=False, alpha_channel=0.85, keep_on_top=True,).Layout(layout)
repeat = 1
        
       

def onCall():           # Should/can the name of this function match input of button txt?

    applescript = (
       """
set people to "{1}"

    tell application "Messages"
    repeat with myBuddy in buddies
        --get properties of myBuddy
        if name of myBuddy is in people then
            send "{2}" to myBuddy
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
"""
        
    .format(
            repeat, people, msg1   
        )
    )
    args = [
        item
        for x in [("-e", l.strip()) for l in applescript.split("\n") if l.strip() != ""]
        for item in x
    ]
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["osascript"] + args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    progname = proc.stdout.read().strip()



# Button Loop

while True:             
    event, values = window.Read()
    if event == 'ON CALL':
        sound(),onCall()
    elif event== sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
sys.exit()








def main():
    onCall()
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: As this is not a question having a "technical" kind of problem checkout SO sister-site where you're question better fits. My guess would be to start at software engineering or so.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Multiline` as multi-line input, like your message and status, and use `Combo` as input or selection of contact.

```py
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def update_contact(contacts, contact):
    if contact:
        if contact not in contacts:
            contacts.append(contact)
            contacts = sorted(contacts)
            combo.update(value=contact, values=contacts)

def send_message(window, contact, message):
    sleep(1)    # Simulate to send message
    window.write_event_value('Sent', (contact, message))

font = ("Courier New", 11)
sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
sg.set_options(font=font)

contacts = []

layout = [
    [sg.Combo(contacts, default_value='', size=30, expand_x=True, key="Contact"),
     sg.Button("Send")],
    [sg.Multiline("On a Call", size=(40,10), key='Message', text_color='white', background_color='green')],
    [sg.Multiline('', size=(40, 5), key='Status', text_color='white', background_color='green')],
]

window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)
combo, status = window['Contact'], window['Status']
combo.bind('<Return>', ' Return')

while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Contact Return':
        contact = values['Contact'].strip()
        update_contact(contacts, contact)
    elif event == 'Send':
        contact = values['Contact'].strip()
        update_contact(contacts, contact)
        message = values['Message'].strip()
        if contact and message:
            Thread(target=send_message, args=(window, contact, message), daemon=True).start()
            window['Message'].update('')
    elif event == 'Sent':
        conatct, message = values[event]
        message_formated = '\n'.join(map(lambda x: " "*2+x, message.split('\n')))
        status.update(f"Message sent\nRecipient: {contact}\nMessage  : \n{message_formated}")

window.close()
```